# Zend: Accessing model from Bootstrap raises an exception

Tags: exception, zend-framework, model, bootstrapping

This is the code I have in Bootstrap:

```
public function _initRegistry()
{
    $systemConfigModel = new Application_Model_DbTable_SystemConfig();
    Zend_Registry::set('config', $systemConfigModel->getSystemConfig());
}
```

And this an exception I am getting:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Table_Exception' with message 'No adapter found for Application_Model_DbTable_SystemConfig' in /usr/share/php5/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php on line 755
( ! ) Zend_Db_Table_Exception: No adapter found for Application_Model_DbTable_SystemConfig in /usr/share/php5/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php on line 755
```

It works just fine if I call it within my `BaseController`. It just looks like the PDO adapter that I specify in `application.ini` has not been initialized at the time Bootstrap is executed (strange?). What should I do to make the code work in Bootstrap? Is it necessary to create and set an adapter with Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter();?

I am asking because if the code is not in Bootstrap, it needs to be duplicated in two different places and it also kind of looks like it belongs to Bootstrap.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct, during bootstrap, the Zend Application resource for your database has not yet been initialized.

Try changing your bootstrap method as follows so you explicitly bootstrap the db resource.

```
public function _initRegistry()
{
    $this->bootstrap('db'); // Bootstrap the db resource from configuration

    $db = $this->getResource('db'); // get the db object here, if necessary

    // now that you have initialized the db resource, you can use your dbtable object
    $systemConfigModel = new Application_Model_DbTable_SystemConfig();
    Zend_Registry::set('config', $systemConfigModel->getSystemConfig());
}
```

Comment: +1! More information here - [Zend Application – Theory of Operation – Dependency Tracking](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.theory-of-operation.html#zend.application.theory-of-operation.bootstrap.dependency-tracking)